# Outlook 2007: Reply and Forward Fails to Use Default Formatting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, format, reply

I have a HTML signature in use in Outlook 2007. I have set the default formatting values to align with the text in the email signature, which works for new emails and for reply/forward emails that use these same values.

A problem occurs when replying or forwarding received emails from other users. It seems that it uses the settings from the received email and not the default settings (0.65cm indent).

I have found this to be the logical cause of the problem as I changed the settings to NOT include the previous email in Replies, and it worked without a problem. This is for a financial company and the inclusion of the previous emails within the string are a legal requirement, so MUST be included.

Is there a way to force the system to use the default settings?

Is a registry value change required?

I have attempted to seek an answer to the change of registry value, without any luck. My knowledge on registry values is very limited, so I don't know where to start with these, and am not that keen on poking around in there in case I cause some unknown irreparable damage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards.
Kevin.