# Outlook macro to change "style set" on reply

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, formatting, macros

I have to following issue: With Outlook 2010 - or Outlook in general - when you reply on a email with HTML format, then some formatting is used from the received email.

Often the paragraph settings are different from my template. I found a simple way to change the formatting to my standard settings:

> In the open email, on the ribbon choose:
>   Tab "Format Text", click on "Change Styles" on the right, choose
>   "Style Set", select "Word 2003"

Now I would like to create a macro that does that task automatically when I select "reply", "reply all" or "forward".

Unfortunately Outlook does not have a macro recorder :(
I found something similar but there is no response at all: [Outlook 2007: Reply and Forward Fails to Use Default Formatting](https://superuser.com/questions/809733/outlook-2007-reply-and-forward-fails-to-use-default-formatting) 
Or this macro here does not work: http://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/set-email-reply-format-automatically/

What would be the macro code to do the above steps in the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just apply the required style set and then select **Set as Default** in the bottom of **Change Styles** menu.

Or you can do something like this:

```vb
Public WithEvents OutlookInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Public WithEvents OutlookInspector As Outlook.Inspector

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set OutlookInspectors = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub OutlookInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    Set OutlookInspector = Inspector
End Sub

Private Sub OutlookInspector_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Item As MailItem

    If Not OutlookInspector Is Nothing Then
        Set Item = OutlookInspector.CurrentItem
        If Not Item Is Nothing And Item.Size = 0 Then
            OutlookInspector.WordEditor.ApplyQuickStyleSet "Word 2003"
        End If
    End If

    Set OutlookInspector = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for that idea but I have already tried that without success. The default setting does not work for all emails I reply to.

Comment: Updated the answer by including VBA macro

Comment: THIS WORKS, just make sure you enable macros for Outlook first: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1368-outlook-enable-disable-macros.html

Comment: Could you see the following question, which may have a very similar answer?  
https://superuser.com/questions/1504009/different-default-style-set-for-new-emails-and-to-notes-in-new-contacts-appoint  
The first two lines of code give are marked in red as errors in the BVA editor.