# Different default Style Set for new emails and to notes in new contacts, appointments and tasks of Microsoft Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, styles, contacts, appointments

I formatted a Microsoft Outlook 365 email in my PC the way I want all new emails to be formatted by default. (An example of such settings: The left and right margins were set to 3 cm.)

Then, I saved the setting as the default: Format Text → Styles → Change Styles → Set as Default.

I also saved the Style Set with the name "Emails" and the extension `dotx` of Word Templates: Format Text → Styles → Change Styles → Style Set → Save as New Style Set → Emails.dotx.
In the folder where Outlook led me to save Emails.dotx, C:\Users\rodol\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\QuickStyles, there was another Style Set, Outlook.dotx, that I had created or modified in the past.

I was a happy man until I created a new Contact. When I wanted to add some notes in the `Notes` area, I was unhappy to see that the 3-cm margins appeared there. I had to open my old Style Set by the name of Outlook.dotx to fix the formatting. (Same story with notes to Callendar and Tasks items).

Is there a way to have a Style Set for emails and another for notes to other items?

If not, is there a way to add an automatically executed macro to change the Style Set of every new mail?

If not, is there a way to add a shortcut to choose a specific Style Set?

Comment: In my opinion, you could create a new Style instead of changing the default style. Apply it when composing a new email

Comment: @Perry Yes, this is what I am doing by now. I created a Style Set for emails and I added a Style Set button to the Quick Access Toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most you can do is

- to keep the default style set,
- to create a style set for emails and
- to add a style set button to the Quick Access Toolbar in order to easily select the style set for emails whenever you write one.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I generally do it:

- new mail.
- create new text, edit its font, color, size, ecc.
- save them as new style [1]: select the text → (a mini style menu pops up) → from that one select styles → create a style → ...your choices...
- save the Style Set with the name "Emails" and the extension dotx of Word Templates: Format Text → Styles → Change Styles → Style Set → Save as New Style Set → Emails.dotx.
- save the mail: File → Save
- close the mail.
- new mail.
- load the previous style set:  Format Text → Styles → Change Styles → Style sets → (under paragraph "custom") select the style you saved before.
- save the mail: File → Save
- save the setting as the default: Format Text → Styles → Change Styles → Set as Default
- save the mail: File → Save
- close the mail.
- close Outlook
- reopen Outlook

Whenever you stuble into a popup asking if you want to keep/save your changes, press "yes".

Now every new mail you create should have the style set you selected as default.

The key point is **saving the mail after almost every operation**.

[1] You can massively import new style in a mail from a Word document by copying the whole ocntent of the Word document into the mail, then deleting the whole mail body, and then save the style set (the word document styles are automatically loaded into the outlook style gallery)